# Laravel Eloquent's ->load() With Callback Not Affecting Resultset

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am looking to take a parent object (`Person`, in this example) and load a bunch of relationships on it, many of which have custom query parameters passed to `->load()` as a callback. For example:

```
public function some_method(Request $request, Person $person) {

$person->load([
   'things' => function ($query) {
      $query->where('status', 'active')
         ->whereDate('created_at', '<', '2021-01-01');
   },
   'other_things' => function ($query) {
      $query->where('status', 'active')
         ->where('color', 'red');
   },
   ... Many more callback-based relationships ...
]);
```

When I pass this to a Blade template with `return view('...', compact('person'))` and begin looping over some of the relationships like this:

```
@foreach ($person->things as $thing)
{{ $thing->status == 'active' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}
@endforeach
```

I get many `Thing`s that are inactive and do not conform to the `->whereDate()` query from the `->load()` function in the controller. I would expect the custom callbacks in the `load([...])` to filter the resulting relationship, but when accessing the relationships in Blade templates, it seems the query is executed as if there are no callback functions present.

I have tried using `with()` but that does not appear to be the correct way to approach it, considering I am injecting the `Person` in the URI. I have also tried using `->map()` with various loop structures, but those also get overwritten by what appears to be a second round of Eloquent calls to the database.

What do I need to do in order to have the Blade template "respect" the custom callback queries that I wish to use to filter the records loaded onto the parent object?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading.

Comment: 8, and what your link shows is exactly what I am doing. However, those custom query parameters are not reflected in the Blade file; the SQL queries to retrieve the relationships are executed without any `WHERE `statements.

Comment: might be a stupid question but have you tried to use `$person = $person->load(...` so override the `$person` with the `load` result?

Comment: Yes I have, unfortunately. I have also tried `$person = collect($person->load(...))` but that causes a host of other problems, like timestamps not being cast, JSON not being parsed, etc.

Comment: And disabled lazy loading https://laravel-news.com/disable-eloquent-lazy-loading-during-development?

Comment: That did it, and alerted me to a place where I was missing the entry in `load()`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can try.

**Option 1**

this should not be needed but you can try and override the `$person` with the loaded result.

```php
$person = $person->load();
```

**Option 2**

As of Laravel [8.43](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.43.0) you can use `Model::preventLazyLoading(! app()->isProduction());` in the `boot` method of `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`. This will prevent any lazy loading , also in views. If there is lazy loading it will return an error.[image] [image source](https://laravel-news.com/disable-eloquent-lazy-loading-during-development)

Comment: Thank you very much!